# Invalid mapping while running gulp

Tags: gulp

im trying to run gulp in node console and I get an error like below. I was looking over the net for a solution, but nothing has work so far. Hope you can help me.

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\wicie\wp-content\themes\domki-wicie\node_modules\source-map\lib\source-map-generator.js:298
      throw new Error('Invalid mapping: ' + JSON.stringify({
      ^

Error: Invalid mapping: {"generated":{"line":157,"column":3},"source":"../bower_components/bootstrap/scss/mixins/_hover.scss","original":{"line":12,"column":-19},"name":null}
    at SourceMapGenerator_validateMapping [as _validateMapping] (C:\xampp\htdocs\wicie\wp-content\themes\domki-wicie\node_modules\source-map\lib\source-map-generator.js:298:13)
    at SourceMapGenerator_addMapping [as addMapping] (C:\xampp\htdocs\wicie\wp-content\themes\domki-wicie\node_modules\source-map\lib\source-map-generator.js:110:12)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\wicie\wp-content\themes\domki-wicie\node_modules\concat-with-sourcemaps\index.js:60:28
    at Array.forEach ()
    at BasicSourceMapConsumer.SourceMapConsumer_eachMapping [as eachMapping] (C:\xampp\htdocs\wicie\wp-content\themes\domki-wicie\node_modules\source-map\lib\source-map-consumer.js:157:14)
    at Concat.add (C:\xampp\htdocs\wicie\wp-content\themes\domki-wicie\node_modules\concat-with-sourcemaps\index.js:58:18)
    at DestroyableTransform.bufferContents [as _transform] (C:\xampp\htdocs\wicie\wp-content\themes\domki-wicie\node_modules\gulp-concat\index.js:68:12)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._read (C:\xampp\htdocs\wicie\wp-content\themes\domki-wicie\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:182:10)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._write (C:\xampp\htdocs\wicie\wp-content\themes\domki-wicie\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:170:83)
    at doWrite (C:\xampp\htdocs\wicie\wp-content\themes\domki-wicie\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:406:64)
```

Node version - 8.9.4
npm version - 5.6.0
source-map version - 0.6.1

Comment: I found this: https://discourse.roots.io/t/gulp-error-invalid-mapping-json-stringify/8389/12